# Powershell use pattern matching in filenames

Tags: powershell

I'm not that great with Powershell and I'm facing a simple problem. I'm building an automatic Nuget package publish script and for that I need to push the nuget package with a file name like this "Name.version.nupkg". The version number changes so I would need to find a file that matches the patter with changing version number.

Currently the script is a simple script:

```
cd $PSScriptRoot
dotnet nuget push ..\bin\Debug\MacroFramework.*.nupgk --api-key --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

$PSScriptRoot is "MacroFrameworkLibrary/Local"

And the output is:

```
error: File does not exist (..\bin\Debug\MacroFramework.*.nupgk).
```

Image of the directory content here:

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance

EDIT: The final working script is as follows:

```
cd $PSScriptRoot
$files = Get-ChildItem ..\bin\Debug\MacroFramework.*.nupkg | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

foreach ($pgk in $files)
{
  dotnet nuget push $pgk.FullName --api-key --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dotnet nuget push` doesn't support wildcards in paths.

You can get around this by using the wildcard in `Get-ChildItem`, sorting by date descending, then piping the first match to `dotnet nuget push`.

Here's an example. `gci` is an alias of `Get-ChildItem`, `|` means to send its output as input to the next command, and `% { }` is a for-each loop. Inside the loop, `$_` refers to the current item.

```
cd $PSScriptRoot
gci ..\bin\Debug\MacroFramework.*.nupkg | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 1 | % { dotnet nuget push $_.FullName --api-key --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed from the & {} to a foreach loop. The working script is in the answer.

Comment: @porras Glad it helped. I missed that you only wanted the most recent nupkg. I added sorting by date descending and selecting the first result to my answer. That eliminates the need for the `break` and guarantees that the first item in the for-each is the most recent: `$files = Get-ChildItem ..\bin\Debug\MacroFramework.*.nupkg | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: thanks, I updated the script for the original question as well.